# how configure paypal payment with creditcard

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I try to create a payment a with credit card with this and  get response from paypal 
with success ACK but in IPN i aim getting and pending response, Why im getting this error when i try to payment with this

```
METHOD=DoDirectPayment
&VERSION=64
&PWD=1366191702
&USER=emial.gmail.com
&SIGNATURE=123.aqswdece-eddsfsdfsfsfsdfsdf
&AMT=5
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
&PAYMENTACTION=Authorization
&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa
&ACCT=4514409288528467
&EXPDATE=52018
&CVV2=123
&FIRSTNAME=dasdjhasd
&LASTNAME=kjhadajshd
&STREET=sdadas
&CITY=kjhfkjhas
&STATE=jhsfkjhs
&COUNTRYCODE=BR
&ZIP=123
&IPADDRESS=127.0.0.1
&CUSTOM=hasib
&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard
```

**Response**

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014-09-15T10:35:10Z
[CORRELATIONID] => c48d94194583f
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 64
[BUILD] => 12786467
[AMT] => 5.00
[CURRENCYCODE] => USD
[AVSCODE] => X
[CVV2MATCH] => M
[TRANSACTIONID] => 43Y54124LX916011P
```

But my problem is that i not receive any amount to my Business  account.

and my IPN response is

```
mc_gross] => 5.00
    [auth_exp] => 03:21:03 Oct 15, 2014 PDT
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [payer_id] => 9KGRGK8Y9TS
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payment_date] => 03:21:03 Sep 15, 2014 PDT
    [payment_status] => Voided
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [first_name] => dasdjhasd
    [transaction_entity] => auth
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [custom] => hasib
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [business] => debal_@gmail.com
    [quantity] => 1
    [verify_sign] => AVkS-8Ls6tx5AbNI99G2ey8uZF.MLmGc89-G9mNP
    [parent_txn_id] =>
    [txn_id] => 7T575390RR596494D
    [payment_type] => instant
    [remaining_settle] => 0
    [auth_id] => 7T575390RR596494D
    [last_name] => kjhadajshd
    [receiver_email] => debal_biz@gmail.com
    [auth_amount] => 5.00
    [receiver_id] => 7B79NQ4HXGZTW
    [txn_type] => web_accept
    [item_name] =>
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_number] =>
    [residence_country] => BR
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [receipt_id] => 2321-3124-0468-4638
    [handling_amount] => 0.00
    [transaction_subject] =>
    [payment_gross] => 5.00
    [auth_status] => Voided
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [ipn_track_id] => 182a6b385e18
```

Answer (score 1):

In the DoDirect API call you are passing the "PAYMENTACTION=AUTHORIZATION" which means you have to capture the payment either by logging to the PayPal account or via the API. Untill the authorized type transaction is captured it will remain in pending status for 29 days and after that it will be expired . If you want the money to come right away in your account change "PaymentAction=SALE" . Once its done you will see money in your account and ipn will be sent with status = completed .